# Include files with $_GET switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

guys! I am a newbie. I think about it all day but still not much..

I have one index.php file, one switch statement:

```
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];

    switch ($current_page) {
        case ('homepage'):
            include 'contents/homepage.php';
            break;
        case ('about'):
            include 'contents/about.php';
            break;
        case ('contacts'):
            include 'contents/contacts.php';
            break;
        default:
            include 'contents/homepage.php';
    }
```

I include a file if the get attribute is some of the names.
And if the URL is for example: myproject/index.php?page=about
The proper content file is included.

But when the URL is just: myproject/index.php
No file is included.

I was thinkig to add something like:

```
    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
        header('Location: index.php?page=homepage');
    }
```

But it is kind of ugly I think and the URI cannot be nver just index.php.. And what if the parameter is not "page"... It is a problem again.

Do you have in mind some simple understandable solution for this. How to include the proper contents according to the different pages?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So if there's no page parameter, you want it skip including an external file?

Comment: only practical for a very small site.

Comment: jboneca, ya something like that, but the default case with homepage including is nice for me too.
Dagon, yes I thought so too. Can you briefly throw an idea what would be better solution even for small project or if the project grow bigger? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when checking if an array's key is set, use `array_key_exists` instead. It is much faster for the parser.

Second, you shouldn't redirect the page. Instead, use a default value, like so:

```
// Set default value
$current_page = 'homepage';

// Change value if `page` is specified
if(array_key_exists('page',$_GET) {
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];
}

// Check page
switch ($current_page) {
    case 'about':
        include 'contents/about.php';
        break;
    case 'contacts':
        include 'contents/contacts.php';
        break;
    case 'homepage':
    default:
        include 'contents/homepage.php';
}
```

Additionally, as I have done above, you don't need to specify the include for homepage twice. Without a `break` statement, the parser will go into the next case statement. If you want to treat multiple values the same, you can simply specify them subsequently.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Swivelgames! Is it right that I can even remove the **"case 'homepage':"** line and the default case would do this job - to load the homepage include content file in the index? This means probably if the parameter in the URL is not existing, again the homepage content will be loaded. This is good I think, right? This **if(array_key_exists('page',$_GET)** seems very nice. I can check for other parameters if I have in the future and include another different files.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly correct. Another method you could do is use the `default` case for displaying a 404 page. In otherwords, move the `include 'contents/homepage.php'` into the `case 'homepage':`, and then use the `default` to `include 'contents/404.php'`. Just a thought... the wonderful thing about programming is that you can do whatever you want with it! :)

Comment: I read that including files using page parameters (as in my approach) is not good. I searched a lot across the Internet but I did not find any solution for this. Can you suggest something if you know anything about it? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: @AntonRadev, Not in terms of the approach used above. The issue is in terms of security when you're using the variable name to act as the filename, as in `include 'contents/'.$current_page.'.php';`. The problem is, as a malicious visitor, I can pass in a value into `$_GET['page']` that will allow me to access other files on your machine, that you're not expecting. However, as long as you're deliberate with the request variables, you should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'homepage';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : null;

    switch ($current_page) {
        case ('homepage'):
            include 'contents/homepage.php';
            break;
        case ('about'):
            include 'contents/about.php';
            break;
        case ('contacts'):
            include 'contents/contacts.php';
            break;
        default:
            include 'contents/homepage.php';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Is this means $current_page is the 'page' parameter OR there is no parameter?